# how to display the address of a node in linked list in C

Tags: c, linked-list

```
void insert_end()
{
    struct node *nn=(struct node*)malloc(sizeof(struct node));
    printf("Enter the data:");
    scanf("%d",&nn->info);
    nn->next=NULL;
    if(first==NULL)
    {
        first=nn;
        first->next=first;
    }
    else
    {
        temp=first;
        while(temp->next!=first)
            temp=temp->next;
        temp->next=nn;
        nn->next=first;
        printf("The address of the first node is %d", first);
        printf("The address of the last node is %d", nn->next);
    }
}
```

This is a Circular Linked List, Insertion function in C.

I need to show that the address of the first node and the link part of the last node have the same value, thus showing that it is a circular linked list.

But my code above gives random integer values..!

Comment: In C we don't cast the return from `malloc`. Search this site for why.

Answer (score 8):

You might want to print the addresses with `%p`

```
    printf("The address of the first node is %p",first);
    printf("The address of the last node is %p",nn->next);
```

Answer (score 2):

The only addresses you can portably print are void pointers. This is not a big restriction, since you can convert any object pointer to a void pointer and back. The `printf` specifier for ptr-to-void is `%p`:

```
printf("The address of the first node is %p\n", (void *)first);
printf("The address of the last node is %p\n", (void *)nn->next);
```

Note that the `(void *)` casts are **required to avoid undefined behavior**.

Answer (score 0):

<strike>printf("The address of the last node is &d,nn->next);</strike>

This is not correct. 
Try using the following to printf the address of a pointer variable.

```
     printf("The address of the last node is 0x%p",nn->next);

    /* 
       Below Will Fail To Print Correctly 
       if sizeof(int) != sizeof(void*) 
    */
    printf("The address of the last node is 0x%x",nn->next);
```

Commonly used format specifiers are listed [here](http://poeticcoding.com/main/c-programing/format-specifiers-in-c/).

Comment: This is undefined behavior in any case. %x does not accept pointers, only integers.

Comment: yes its undefined, but as long as int and pointer have same size %x should display address correctly. 

As arguments to printf are passed as value.   
So if Address is 0x01010101 and is passed as value.  
it should be read as 4 byte number only inside printf(...)  

Please correct me if I'm wrong?

Comment: You're wrong. Undefined is undefined is undefined. Any speculation is bogus. There's a way to print pointers in a defined way. Use it.